# Definition of the class $\alpha\mathbf{X}+\beta\mathbf{Y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Shilov's *Linear Algebra*, and can't understand how the definition of the class $\alpha\mathbf{X}+\beta\mathbf{Y}$ works.

Shilov defines two vectors to be comparable like this:

[image: FIGURE 1]

He then defines a class as follows:

[image: FIGURE 2]

The following is where I'm having trouble:

[image: FIGURE 3]

The given space is $\mathbf{K}$ and the subspace with respect to which we are deciding the comparability of vectors is $\mathbf{L}$. Let's let the fixed variable be $k$ (serves the same purpose as $x$ in figure 2.)

From figure 3, $x\in\mathbf{X}$ and $y\in\mathbf{Y}$. This implies, $k-x\in\mathbf{L}$ and $k-y\in\mathbf{L}$. Then we have two scalars, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the field $K$. Figure 3 claims that there is a class $\mathbf{Z}$ such that $\alpha x + \beta y \in\mathbf{Z}$.

This must mean that
$$k - (\alpha x + \beta y)\in\mathbf{L}\tag{1}$$

How can I show $(1)$ is true?